# Posting JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, post, request

I want to post username and password to my backend.
Problem is that the data doesn't reach my backend, with following code:

```js
function register() {


  var text = '{"username":"admin1","password":"1234"}';

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8087/meetmeserver/api/admin/register", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(text));

}
```

If I leave out the line with `xhr.setRequestHeader`, it reaches my backend but throwing an exception...

Does anyone now where my problem is? I really would appreciate your help. If you need more code just tell me.

Comment: You don't need to use `.stringify()` on a string.

Comment: so it should be just xhr.send(text)  ?

Comment: Yes buddy. Try that and let me know?

Comment: still... my Backend dont get the data... there must be something wrong with the xhr.setRequest. Because when I leave it out, the data reaches my backend.

Comment: my Rest API @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) btw.

Comment: and when I post a application/json with postman, everything works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. The problem was that both my backend and my frontend were on localhost, but on different ports. There are some security options in your browser which are blocking this.

If you need more information on this look here: 
["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

also here is my improved javaScript... :)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8087/meetmeserver/api/admin/register',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```